# How to store file in a disk and reference it in Postgres database and sync up?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to store as a file in server. It may be in the disk and store the path of that file in Postgres table. I know storing the file in the disk in no more Sync up in the Postgres. It may happen that someone deletes that file on the disk and my column still referencing it. So, I go deep down and find that **Postgres has some feature which allows users to save the file in the disk and create a symbolic link and stored in the database itself which allows to sync up**. It also works as a backup. **I also want to control the file from accessing it based on some condition**. How can we do it in Postgres? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either store files in the filesystem and put their file names or paths into the database (but that way you will have to remember about those files when you do backups or migrate data) or you can let Postgres store the files in the database using BLOB, bytea or text data types.

See the documentation:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-binary.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html

If you store files in the database then they will be backed up automatically, you will have ACID and other database goodies.

If you store files in the file system then you are pretty much on your own, but the performance characteristics may have some advantages for certain use cases.

There is also a third option of storing files in services like S3, Cloudinary, Uploadcare etc. and storing their IDs (usually UUIDs) in the database - which is a pretty common use case for certain data, especially user-uploaded photos etc.

See this for more info:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB

Comment: I know we can store the file in a BLOB, but what I want to know is how we can store in some kind of disk and create a symbolic link in the database for sync up. Storing the path in the database is an old hack and it's not got back up or any more sync. I know Oracle provides some File Column that behaves like same. Instead of storing in the blob, It stores the file in database storage itself and creates a symbolic link in the column. So, My file behaves like it is in the database itself.